# How to use slider to other view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 views, View_A and View_B. I have a slider on View_A and a touchesMoved method on View_B. The slider has a method_A as follow.

```
- (void)method_A: (float)value{

value = [slider value];

}
```

I hope to adjust the slider to change a float in touchesMoved on View_B. The float is send to ViewB but touchesMoved don't receive. Can anyone tell me how to pass the float into touchesMoved? Thanks a lot.

Comment: your  View_A and View_B. are on same viewController ??

Comment: No, View_A and View_B are on 2 different viewController.

Comment: ViewCon2 *obj = [[ViewCon2 alloc] init]; obj.muValue = valuofSlider;[self presentmodeViewController:obj...];

Comment: I assume that muValue in your example is a float? If so, the value won't be updated when the slider changes...

Comment: Are View_A and View_B shown at the same time?  If not, you just need to pass the final value to View_B.